# the Markdown processor Grip broke with a bug in its Flask module hitting Github's API

Tags: github, flask, grip

I used Grip to convert my README.md file into HTML for our project's Help page.

Here's a version of Grip: https://github.com/joeyespo/grip

It turns out Grip has been hitting Github's API to actually cook the Markdown, and today it failed with an error in its Flask layer, which I'm not certified in:

```
[2024-03-10 08:24:33,930] ERROR in app: Exception on / [GET]
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 2070, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1515, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1513, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1499, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**req.view_args)
File "/usr/share/grip/grip/app.py", line 174, in _render_page
    content = self.renderer.render(text, self.auth)
File "/usr/share/grip/grip/renderers.py", line 101, in render
    r.raise_for_status()
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/models.py", line 943, in raise_for_status
    raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 415 Client Error: Unsupported Media Type for url: https://api.github.com/markdown/raw
```

my Grip version is 4.2.0. I'm socializing out the error here in case anyone else hits it. Where is the latest version of Grip?

Comment: the fix for my outer problem is replace Grip with curl: `curl -L -X POST -H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" -H "X-GitHub-Api-Version: 2022-11-28" https://api.github.com/markdown -d @README.json > doc/Help.html`. The inner problem with Grip still needs a fix, but we won't go back because Grip adds unneeded clutter to the output HTML.